# Specifying Relationship Fields in Eloquent Models using pivot tables on existing table schema

Tags: php, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-5.6

Whilst reading [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps) on Laravel for pivot tables I have hard time guessing on how I can specify the appropriate field whilst moving/redesighning the php code of my current project into Laravel.

The problem that I have is that on my existing project I have the following tables:

```
ohimeSama:
id: Primary Key
namae: String

oujiSama
id: Primary Key
namae: String

suki:
id: pk
princess_id: Foreighn Key Ohimesama
prince_id: Foreighn Key Oujisama
```

For the `Ohimesama` table I set the following Model:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\Suki;
use App\Model\Oujisama;


class Ohimesama extends Model
{
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $table = "ohimesama";

   public function princesThatShesInLove()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Oujisama::class)->using(Suki::class);
   }
}
```

Same for the `Oujisama`:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\Ohimesama
use App\Model\Suki;

class Oujisama extends Model
{
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $table = "ohimesama";

   public function lovedByPrincess()
   {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ohimesama::class)->using(Suki::class);
   }
}
```

Also, the pivot Model for `Suki` is:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Suki extends Pivot
{
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $table = "suki";
}
```

So I want to know how I can specify the appropriate relationship fields representing the foreign keys on table `suki`? In the documentation I find hard to figure out how these fields are being specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the problem you need to follow these 2 major steps:

1. Specify the foreighn keys in the pivot model `Suki` via relationships:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
use App\Model\Oujisama;
use App\Model\Ohimesama;

class Suki extends Pivot
{
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $table = "suki";

   public function ohimesama()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo(Ohimesama::class, 'princess_id');
   }



   public function ohimesama()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo(Oujisama::class, 'prince_id');
   }
}
```

2. Then on the relationship definition you specify the return pk of the model you want to return. Using the Pivot as fk resolver, In out case we will define our `Ohimesama` model:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\Suki;
use App\Model\Oujisama;


class Ohimesama extends Model
{
   public $timestamps = false;
   protected $table = "ohimesama";

   public function princesThatShesInLove()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Oujisama::class,'suki','id','id')->using(Suki::class);
   }
}
```

If `Oujisama` had as pk `oujisama_id` instead of plain `id`, then the relationship definition would be:

```
 return $this->belongsToMany(Oujisama::class,'suki,'id','oujisama_id')->using(Suki::class);
```

Similar, the `OujiSama`'s relation is defined as well.